# Auth::guard('memberweb')->user() returning null after redirection

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel-modules packages "https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v3/introduction" in order to better structure my application.

I have a user model created with the artisan command "make::auth" which is located in App, and a Member model which is located inside the Modules folder.
[image]

The issue is that after I login with the member guard and redirected to /member/profile Auth::guard('memberweb')->user() always returns null.
But if I dd(Auth::guard('memberweb')->user()) in the login method of the MemberLoginController :

```
/**
 * Member Login
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
      $this->validate($request, [
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'password' => 'required',
      ]);

    // Attempt to log the member in
      if (Auth::guard('memberweb')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        dd(Auth::guard('memberweb')->user());
        return redirect()->intended(route('memberProfile'));
      }
      // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
      return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->with('error','your credentials donnot match our records');
}
```

the object is returned as expected. It looks like after being redirected the member gets logout.

And my config.auth.guards looks like so:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'memberweb' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'members',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'memberweb-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'members',
    ],
],
```

And my Kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'memberAuth' => \Modules\Member\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfMemberAuthenticated::class,
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\Roles::class,
    'permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\Permissions::class,
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: facing same issue, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the routes.php file. You need to add also the web guard before the auth.

so, for example, my route.php looked like that:

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:developer|admin']], 
function()
{
Route::get('/dashboard/users', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@index')->name('dashboardUsers');
Route::get('/dashboard/user/{id}/edit', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit')->name('dashboardEditUserView');
Route::post('/dashboard/user/{id}/edit', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@update')->name('dashboardEditUserView');
});
```

but should look like this:

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth','role:developer|admin']], 
function()
{
Route::get('/dashboard/users', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@index')->name('dashboardUsers');
Route::get('/dashboard/user/{id}/edit', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit')->name('dashboardEditUserView');
Route::post('/dashboard/user/{id}/edit', 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers\UserController@update')->name('dashboardEditUserView');
});
```